# Does Mizuho reveal his crossdressing after he graduates?

Tags: otoboku-maidens-are-falling-for-me

It's been a long time since I watched *Otoboku*, but I've always wondered if the visual novel explained what happens to Mizuho after he graduates and puts aside his façade.

Mizuho is a guy disguised as a girl, attending an all-girls school. He doesn't exactly keep a low profile, either; if he'd done that, he could have just made his girl form disappear after graduation and went back to being a man. Instead, he runs for Elder and becomes a celebrity who is looked up to by the younger girls. When he graduates, he can't just throw off his wig and dress, go "Phew, what a relief", and be a man again, because tons of his former classmates recognize him. He would have to either tell them all "Yeah, I was cross-dressing all those years and hanging out in the dressing room and bathrooms with you" and get arrested for a pervert, or else pretend to be his own brother (or something) and get out the disguise again whenever his old school friends come around.

[image: Mizuho hair flipping]

Yes, seriously, that's a guy.

If I remember correctly, Mariya, Takako, and Shion all know by the end of the anime series that Mizuho is a guy. Yukari and Kana never find out. So at some point, he's going to have to break it to Yukari and Kana, even if he decides to never see anyone else from the school again. (According to [the Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Otome_wa_Boku_ni_Koishiteru_characters#Main_characters), though, he, Shion, and Takako often visit their old school after graduation.)

The Wikipedia article says the VN does show what Mizuho does after he graduates. Does it address this? Does he maintain his female disguise or eventually break it to everyone that he was a guy the whole time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Not really. After graduating, Mizuho maintains his female disguise *only when visiting the academy.*** However, it's never revealed if his other former classmates know about it (though I also failed to find any remarks if they finally know about it).

According to [pixiv encyclopedia (Japanese)](https://dic.pixiv.net/a/%E5%AE%AE%E5%B0%8F%E8%B7%AF%E7%91%9E%E7%A9%82),

> #### 伝説
>
> [...]卒業後は翔陽大学に進学、[...]
> 卒業後もちょくちょく学院にも顔を出している。**大学では男性として、学院に顔を出す際は女装。**[...]
>
> #### Legend
>
> [...] he went to Shoyo University after graduating, [...]
> He was also visiting the academy occasionally. **He was living as a man in the university, but cross-dressing when visiting the academy.** [...]
>
> <sup>(Emphasis mine)</sup>

According to [AniOta Wiki (Japanese)](https://www49.atwiki.jp/aniwotawiki/pages/6568.html)

> 卒業後は翔陽大学という外部の学校に進学。
> **女装を解いてる**のにも関わらず相変わらず女の子に間違われ、翔大名物美少女トリオのひとりに数えられている。
>
> He went to Shoyo University after graduating.
> Even though **he stopped crossdressing**, he was mistaken as a girl regardless of that and as usual, and counted as one of Shoyo's Speciality Trio Beautiful Girl.

---

The story related to the university life is told in the omake scenario from *Yarukibako 2* ([VNDB entry](https://vndb.org/v544)), a fan-disk for Caramel Box's works (the original visual novel).

> Yes, seriously, [that](http://www.caramel-box.com/products/yaruki2/image/wallpaper/mizuho/y2_mizuho_n0640.jpg)'s a guy (**potentially NSFW**: Mizuho in girl's underwear with his natural long-hair)

Comment: Anyway, I don't think I'll play this game... so, if anyone has more specific & detailed references, then feel free to post it as a new answer!